# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int', but in this case the 'method' is a number

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm new to creating videogames with python and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/barbieri/pong.py", line 75, in <module>
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx) # make the ball move (xcor = current cordinate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1808, in setx
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, self._position[1]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3158, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2469, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

for these lines of code:

```
while True:
    wn.update()  
    
    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx) 
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Borders
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1
```

Can somebody help me? Python version: python 3.7.3. Linux operating system.

I am following a tutorial that uses python 3.6, that could be the cause or it's the same?

Comment: Does `if ball.ycor() > 290:` work?

Comment: What is `ball`, what is `ycor`? Show more code please. Did you mean to use `ball.ycor()`?

Comment: The problem is not the version of Python. We need to see the definition of the class ball, attribute ycor.

Comment: Based on the comments, am I right in thinking the original code said `ball.ycor` instead of `ball.ycor()`?  If so, then the problem was just a typo and the question should be closed.  The fact that `ball.ycor()` worked correctly in an integer context 3 lines above suggests this is the case.

Comment: I tried with `ycor()` but it doen't work. I re-edited the question

Comment: Phew, this question is a mess. The title doesn't match the body, the body has been totally overhauled, and there's an [exact duplicate](/q/67255437/4518341) that was migrated in from Super User. Looking at the [first revision](/revisions/67247310/1), it looks like your original question was answered by [MattDMo's comment](/questions/67247310#comment118864373_67247310), right? If so, please ask a new question instead of editing this one. I'm voting to close this question since the original problem was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your code looks like this

```
if ball.ycor() > 290:
```

and not like this

```
if ball.ycor > 290:
```

because if ycor is defined like this

```
class ball():

    def ycor(self):
        ...
```

and you try to access it like this

```
if ball.ycor > 290:
```

then you will get this error

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'
```