# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int', but in this case the 'method' is a number

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I'm new to creating videogames with python (in the porgram I am using turtle) and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/barbieri/pong.py", line 75, in <module>
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx) # make the ball move (xcor = current cordinate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1808, in setx
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, self._position[1]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3158, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2469, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

for these lines of code:

```
while True:
    wn.update()  
    
    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx) 
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Borders
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1
```

Can somebody help me? Python version: 3.7.3. Linux operating system.

I am following a tutorial that uses python 3.6, that could be the cause or it's the same?

Comment: Exact duplicate: [TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int', but in this case the 'method' is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67247310/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-method-and-int-but-in-thi)

Comment: Please don't post questions to multiple sites, or you end up with situations like this where one question is migrated, creating a duplicate on the same site.

Answer (score 0):

I was also a beginning when I saw this tutorial. I also did the same program. This is sure to come because you paused the game on your own instead of the program ending itself. This is will come but in the terminal window and not in the main game window. This is a flaw from the developer who made this program.